# Does the compiler optimize (close) identical FieldByName calls?

Tags: delphi, optimization, delphi-xe2

In some code I'm maintaining, I see two different methods used in `TClientDataSet.OnCalcFields` event handlers:

```
 with DataSet do
 begin
   // 1. Call FieldByName twice
   if AMinDate > FieldByName(SPlanAllocatieFromDate).AsDateTime then
      AMinDate := FieldByName(sPlanAllocatieFromDate).AsDateTime;
   // 2. Put the retrieved FieldByName value in a temp var
   lEmpID := FieldByName(SPlanAllocatieEmpID).AsInteger;
   if lEmpID <> 0 then lTSAllocatedEmpIDs.Add(IntToStr(lEmpID));
 end;
```

Will the compiler (Delphi XE2, Win32 app) optimize method 2 to use a temp var? The two FieldByNames are quite close, you could even say *nested*.

If not, I should rewrite 1. because OnCalcFields executes often.

BTW. I know about Fields[] versus FieldByName(), or using a temp TField var when running an EOF loop, those are not the issue here.

Comment: I personally wouldn't have thought the compiler optimisation is that good. I'd generally err on the side of caution and assign a temp variable anyway and remove all doubt.

Comment: @Johan, see the note *"BTW. I know about Fields[] versus FieldByName()..."* in the question ;-)

Comment: As far as I know, only `gcc` is smart enough to do that.

Comment: @Free How would it manage to prove that there are no side effects and that the answer is the same every time the function is called?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, it does not attempt to prove determinism at all, AFAIK.

Comment: @Free No compiler could reasonably optimise away these function calls

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No version of the Delphi compiler does anything like this.

Such optimizations would require the compiler to be able to prove that the two calls to FieldByName would always give the same result, and there is currently no provision for flagging a method as being deterministic.

Note that it is quite possible in theory (if unlikely in reality) for the two calls NOT to give the same result, in this case e.g. if a different thread deletes a field out of the collection between the first and second call. Generally, the compiler does not know or care at the call site what a particular method call actually does.

Comment: Not only that, but that the function call did not have side-effects

Answer (score 5):

> Does the compiler optimize (close) identical `FieldByName` calls?

No it does not.

The compiler does not look inside function calls to see what is within. It therefore has no way to prove that the value returned by successive calls to a function would be the same. Likewise it has no way to prove that the function has no side-effects. These are the two prerequisites for the optimisation under consideration.

You will need to perform the optimisation yourself, by explicitly adding and using a local variable to store the value returned by a single call to `FieldByName`.

---

Beyond the consideration of performance, I would argue that the use of a local variable to hold the field is semantically much better. This makes it clear to the reader that all actions are performed on the same field. That reason alone would be enough to persuade me to make the change you describe. Don't repeat yourself.

And while we are in code review mode, you might care to reconsider the use of `with`.

Comment: Not sure if this is what you mean but performance-wise, it's best to use field objects that persist across calls to the OnCalcFields, because looking up a field by name is an expensive process and the OnCalcFields even can be called surprisingly often is some situations.  Traditional "persist fields" satisfy this, of course.

Comment: @MartynA Absolutely. The second part of my answer argues that, in addition to the performance benefit, the code is much better if the field lookup is performed once only.